How can I avoid a CORS error when running this JavaScript in Visual Studio/IIS Express?
I know that in our QA and production environments, our system admins can add CORS configuration to allow these requests. While developing in Visual Studio 2022 and using IIS Express, what can I do to keep from raising local CORS errors?
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function initEmbeddedMessaging() {
        try {
            embeddedservice_bootstrap.settings.language = 'en_US';

            embeddedservice_bootstrap.init(
                'someHexValue',
                'Some_Embedded_Service_deployment',
                'https://foobar.com/somepath',
                {
                    scrt2URL: 'https://foobaz.com'
                }
            );
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error loading Embedded Messaging: ', err);
        }
    };
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://foobar.com/somepath/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js' onload='initEmbeddedMessaging()'></script>

The errors being thrown are:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://foobaz.com/embeddedservice/v1/embedded-service-config?orgId=someHexValue&esConfigName=Some_Embedded_Service_deployment&language=en_US. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unable to load Embedded Messaging configuration.
    h https://foobar.com/ESWAbleEmbeddedService1715712189606/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js:145

I have tried adding the following to <system.WebServer> in web.config (but I will probably remove it before proceeding to QA):
      <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
              <remove name="X-Aspnet-Version" />
              <remove name="X-Aspnetmvc-Version" />
              <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
              <remove name="x-powered-by" />
              <remove name="x-aspnet-version" />
              <remove name="x-aspnetmvc-version" />
              <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https:foobar.com https://foobaz.com" />
              <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET" />
              <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
          </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>

TIA!


<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https:foobar.com https://foobaz.com" />

According to your code with this partial configuration, I think you want to set multiple domain values ​​for Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, right?
But as mentioned in the doc:Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the header value is only allowed to be set to */a single domain name. Separating multiple domain names with spaces will not make them all valid.

Limiting the possible Access-Control-Allow-Origin values to a set of allowed origins requires code on the server side to check the value of the Origin request header, compare that to a list of allowed origins, and then if the Origin value is in the list, set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin value to the same value as the Origin value.

In your case you can probably try this way, it should work for you, simply refer to this answer: Enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin for multiple domains in Node.js.

That's a slick solution for Node.js, but I'm looking for a solution for a .NET Web application. The issue may become moot though, if I can just get the system admins to make the changes on the server soon enough. :-)

Have you tried to use the [EnableCors] attribute? Something like in this doc.  Use commas to separate multiple domains in its origins property value. Like this: origins: "http://www.contoso.com,http://www.example.com".
